# Will command line daemon/wallet still be available after the release of the official GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monero-wallet-gui

Will the Monero command line daemon/wallet programs still be available after the release of the official GUI?

Will Monerod will be blended in similarly to how bitcoin core node/wallet is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will command line still be available after the release of the official GUI?

Yes, it will. As far as I know, there will be support for both in the future. Thus, you will have `monero-wallet-cli`, which is the command line wallet, and `monero-wallet-gui`, which will be the GUI wallet.

> Will Monerod will be blended in similarly of what bitcoin core node/wallet is?

In the future, yes, see the feature request opened [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/issues/39). For now, however, `monero-wallet-gui` will be a separate binary that has to run alongside `monerod`. However, the GUI has a progress bar that shows the syncing status of `monerod`. Thus, new users would only have to open `monerod` and let it sync. They can monitor the progress in `monero-wallet-gui`.

Note that `monero-wallet-gui` might not be the official naming, but I used it in this answer for convenience.

Comment: I for one would like to retain the ability to run wallet and node separately.

Comment: I think I misunderstood - I was thinking you meant that you would have to run wallet and node simultaneously from the same executable, but after thinking about it I'm pretty sure you meant you can run either one from the same executable.

Comment: Correct. In the future there will probably also be an option to run them simultaneously from the same executable. However, I think there will always be support for separate executables, because in that case you can run multiple wallets with one daemon, which is quite convenient.

Comment: Yes. But if they were combined in one executable, you could still do that.

Comment: Only if it wouldn't launch another daemon when one is already up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the command line wallet will be available.

In the near future, a RPC wallet daemon will still be needed, and this is currently the same binary used by the command line wallet.

Moreover, it is much easier to add/change features without having to bother with GUI changes at the same time.

Additionally, it means the wallet can be used via ssh, or X-less systems.

Last, it will stay maintained as long as at least one coder keeps on maintaining it, and this is likely to be a long time. However, I could totally see some features being GUI only: for instance integrated QR code generation and recognition (not saying this will be in the GUI, but rather being unsuited for a command line wallet).